# how to go from activity to fragment on button click ,in bottom navigation i'm using fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am using three fragments in bottom navigation bar in my android app and in one of the fragment i am using calendar view and on click of the calendar date i am going to the activity and there i have given a button and on a click of the button i am trying to go to one of the fragment which i'm using in bottom navigation. Can any one tell me how to do that?

i'm using this code :

```
    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
           ft.commit()
```

but it is not working.
i tried this line of code:

```
var i=Intent(this,RemarksFragment::class.java)
        startActivity(i)
```

But this is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

> onClick of calendar date your are Intent to a ActivityX.
>   as you want to come back to the previous activity which has bottom navigation bar.
>
> start the activity for result. so that, you can back to the activity
>   from the ActivityX with some data.

Inside BottomNavActivity

```
val intent = Intent(this@BottomNavActivity, ActivityX::class.java); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 1001); 

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if(requestCode == 1001 && data != null) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // your data will be here
           String value = data.getStringExtra("KEY");
              //based on your value, launch the fragment
        }
    }
}
```

in ActivityX

```
onClick(view : View) {
     val intent = getIntent();
     intent.putExtra("KEY", "VALUE");
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
     finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the start activity for result method:

```
val intent = Intent(this,CalendarActivity::class.java)
startActivityForResult(intent,REQUEST_CODE(int))
```

Then on back pressed of the Calendar activity you can override the onBackPressed method like this:

```
 override fun onBackPressed() {
   val data = Intent().putExtra("key","fragment index to switch")
   setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,data)
   finish()
}
```

Now in your activity with Bottom Navigation Bar :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE(int) && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        val index = data.getIntExtra("key")
        //Then switch your fragment here.
    }
}
```

If you don't want to switch you can set the result as :

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED)
```

Hope this helps.